# AppGyver launching iOS simulator gives error XCode is not installed

Tags: xcode, cordova, ios-simulator, steroids, appgyver

I am using AppGyver, Steroids Installation has been done and I have successfully created the demo project. I am trying to configure the iOS Simulator for Appgyver so that i can launch my app on simulator using steroids command line and debug the app but when i want to simulate it on ios simulator it gives XCode is not installed. But I have XCode installed and Command Line tools too.

`pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables​` - **PRINT**

`pkgutil --pkgs='com.apple.pkg.Xcode.*'`​ - **NO OUTPUT**

When I use `xcode-select --install` It gives "xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed"

When I use `open /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/iOS Simulator.app` - **Simulator Launch**

​
OS Version : Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10
​XCode : 6.1
iOS Simulator : Version 8.1 (550.3)
Node : v0.10.24
NPM : 1.3.21

​​
Please help me to resolve this issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What simulator version do you have installed?

Comment: What is the issue you are trying to resolve?  The simulator never gives an error about Xcode not being installed.  Also, I presume you properly escaped the 'open' command line to see the simulator open.

Comment: @area28 : It is Version 8.1 (550.3)

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia : I am trying to configure the iOS Simulator for Appgyver so that i can launch my app on simulator using steroids command line and debug the app.

Comment: If you run `steroids connect` and then in the terminal, once connected type `s` and hit enter and wait about 10 seconds do you see the simulator open?

Comment: No, It prints error : Xcode is not installed

Comment: Then go install Xcode.  Also, you should look at using simctl for installing and launching your app as that is the supported mechanism.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia : As I have mentioned I have Xcode installed on my system.

Comment: No, you have not said that.  You have given contradictory statements.  What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list' and what happens if you run 'open -a iOS Simulator' and then 'xcrun simctl launch booted com.apple.mobilesafari'?  If Xcode is installed, you'll see the simulator launch and then MobileSafari launch within it.

Comment: When I use `xcrun simctl list` It prints (See the Image http://prntscr.com/6zsv99),  When I use `open -a iOS Simulator` It launch successfully. & after using  `xcrun simctl launch booted com.apple.mobilesafari` It prints com.apple.mobilesafari: 1096 and safari launch on simulator.

Comment: AG employee here! Have you installed Xcode by downloading from Apple or via the Mac App Store? There's an open issue at https://github.com/AppGyver/steroids/issues/713 – this has cropped up so infrequently that we haven't prioritised it.

Comment: @harsa_ I think I have installed Xcode by downloading the dmg file.